# Translating a Line of JS to C# (Unity)

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine

This is a line of JS that I'd like to translate into C#:

```
private var isFalling = false;
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private bool isFalling = false;
```

or

```
bool isFalling = false;
```

because by default variable is private

Answer (score 0):

Actually `var` is the general data type (for say, actually it is an implicit datatype which resolves by the compiler itself) used in JS and many other languages, even in C#.

If I write `var speed = 0;` then `speed` will become an `int` similarly for `bool` as you wrote and other types.

In your case `isFalling` is a flag that should be a `bool`, so you can write it as,

`private bool isFalling = false;`

Comment: It's not the general data type, it's just an implicit type, which the compiler will resolve for you.

Comment: I know, but look at the question, do you get that feelings that I would reply this? Because of the nature of question, I wrote it like this.